# How to pass variable to exception middleware with Django?

Tags: django

In django 1.10, how do I pass a variable to the middleware exception handler?

In the below example, I want to access the passed list ([1,2,3]) in process_exception().

views.py

```
class my_exception(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

def my_view(request):
    ...
    my_var = [1,2,3] # Want to pass this to exception middleware
    raise my_exception(my_var)
```

middleware.py

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class ExceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    # Has been added to settings.py middleware list
    def process_exception(self, request, exception): 
        if type(exception) == my_exception:
            # How to access my_var here?
        ...
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be just `exception.value`? Maybe I'm missing something but if the exception matches the class you are checking, then it should have the data you used to create it.

Comment: Yes, that worked :) Want to create that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would just be `exception.value` since the exception matches the class you are checking. The exception will have the data you used to create it.